# Are there problems that I can run into by minifying graphql queries

Tags: javascript, graphql

I have a graphql query that I'm sending to the server (uses apollo-server) using fetch. I strip all extra whitespace from the query string before I send it. Should I be worried?

```
const query = `
{ 
  thing {
    id
    name
    relatedThing {
      id
      name
      createdAt
    }
  }
}`
```

after `query.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')` I've got...

`"{ thing { id name relatedThing { id name createdAt } } }"`

I haven't had any complains from the server or any weird behaviour, but I don't understand the server demands and whether there's a possibility this could break some queries. Is it possible that I can break some queries by doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the spec:

> White space is used to improve legibility of source text and act as separation between tokens, and any amount of white space may appear before or after any token. White space between tokens is not significant to the semantic meaning of a GraphQL Document, however white space characters may appear within a String or Comment token... Like white space, line terminators are used to improve the legibility of source text, any amount may appear before or after any other token and have no significance to the semantic meaning of a GraphQL Document. Line terminators are not found within any other token.

In other words, there's nothing wrong with what you are doing. There's just two things to keep in mind:

- If your queries include String literals, that particular regex express will also change the value of the String literal as well if it includes more than one space.
- GraphQL returns errors with a location that includes both the line number and character number where the error occurred. By transforming your queries like this, that information will reflect the transformed query and not your original one.

Comment: Then it's clearly a bad idea. Those are important costs and the benefit is not obvious. Thanks